# Apollo Express CORS options

Tags: amazon-web-services, express, graphql, apollo

How do I protect my graphql route from getting queried from unknown resources?

I have these options currently:

```
export const corsOptions = {
  origin: ["https://my-website.com", "https://api.my-website.com"],
  credentials: true,
}

expressApp.use(cors(corsOptions))

apolloServer.applyMiddleware({expressApp, cors: corsOptions})
```

I have it deployed on AWS/Fargate.

Problem is I can still query in Postman from my computer.

Note, I will also have a React-native app to connect to this API.

What is the right CORS options for me?

Comment: Well you ought to read first what CORS actually is. Then you will understand why POSTMAN will always be able to query your public endpoint.

Comment: Is there any way I can make that endpoint private?

Comment: CORS is only a voluntary limitation in your browser, implemented to improve the user's security. If a system containing curl wants to fetch a resource, it can. You need to add authentication to your endpoint - maybe something like JWT?

Comment: Yes, I use JWT for mutations, but not for queries (because I want visitors browse some content without creating an account). Seems like I either add auth for all or use random generated endpoint.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As pointed out in the comments, CORS is only enforced by browsers -- it cannot be used to prevent access to your API from other clients like Postman.

If your API is consumed only by other servers, you can secure it using an API key that can be included in a header or as a URL parameter. API keys can be used to meter and rate-limit consumers of your API as well.

If your API is consumed by a web or native application, using an API key is largely pointless because end users will be able to get a hold of it by either inspecting the source code or sniffing their local traffic. If you require users to login anyway, then you need to just implement the proper authorization mechanism for your queries. If you want some or all of your queries to be accessible without logging in, then your best bet would be to just implement rate-limiting to limit potential abuse.

Comment: Yes, I have implemented rate-limiting in Express. Thanks for the explanation @Daniel.